# Load more JQuery on Smarty Template

Tags: jquery, smarty

I have a piece of code in a smarty template running in Code Igniter Framework showing users Ratings and Comments. Because of the foreach() loop, all the comment divs are loading at once. I want to have a JQuery to load 5 of the results at the page load and then at the botoom of the page to have a button where i can load 5 more each time pressed. 
Can anyone help me please ?

```
{{ if ($comments_count > 0): }}
{{ foreach ($comments as $index=>$comment): }}
  <div class="notepad">
    <div class="notepad-heading">
    <span class="evaluation_comment_date">{{= timespan(strtotime($comment-    >date_time_added),now()).' '.lang('evaluation_ago') }}
    </div>
<table width="750" border="0" align="left">

<tr>
<td width="154"  valign="top"><h6 style="display:inline">{{= lang('comment_rating') }}</h6></td>
<td width="83"><img style="display:inline" src="{{= template_path() . 'images/' . $comment->rating_image }}" alt=""/></td>
<td width="38" rowspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="307" colspan="5" rowspan="5" valign="top">&#8220;{{= $comment->quotation       }}&#8221;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><h6 style="display:inline">{{= lang('comment_rating2') }}</h6>    </td>
    <td valign="top"><img style="display:inline" src="{{= template_path() . 'images/' .     $comment->rating_image2 }}" alt=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><h6 style="display:inline">{{= lang('comment_rating3') }}</h6>   </td>
<td valign="top"><img style="display:inline" src="{{= template_path() . 'images/' . $comment->rating_image3 }}" alt=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><h6 style="display:inline">{{= lang('comment_rating4') }}</h6>    </td>
    <td valign="top"><img style="display:inline" src="{{= template_path() . 'images/' .     $comment->rating_image4 }}" alt=""/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><h6 style="display:inline">{{= lang('comment_rating5') }}</h6>   </td>
    <td valign="top"><img style="display:inline" src="{{= template_path() . 'images/' .     $comment->rating_image5 }}" alt=""/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
  </div>
{{ if ($index+1 != count($comments)): }}<div class="list_separator"></div>{{ endif }}
{{ endforeach }}
{{ else: }}
<h3>{{= lang('evaluation_no_comments') }}</h3>
{{ endif }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just add display:none to hide elements and then show them when user clicks the button. If you have lot of items you will have to get the elements using .ajax call each time a user clicks more button. Write a script that will be called in js with .ajax. Script will retun the new elements (if using SQL look at LIMIT x,y : x - from, y - number of elements). Then in an .ajax callback just append new elements back to the dom(html).

Also to note, you must synhronize the ajax calls. The simplest but not effective method is to add option async: false to .ajax call. Else if you click more buttom multiple times, items may be out of order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actualy, i am using Mysql and i know how to do it that way but it is extremely complex as it requires major modification in many files and dozens of functions. 
An idea is to store all the html produced after the foreach loop into an array and extract (append) the code from the array into a div element. I am not experienced with Ajax,Jquery. Do you have an idea how to do this ? 
Regards.

Comment: Just append the arrays and add them style display:none. When switching page, remove and add display:none appropriately.